# Can add points and synchronize a point layer successfully, but cannot edit within QField

Tags: qgis, point, geopackage, qfield, qfieldsync

I can't seem to edit a simple point feature layer in QField. I have a point feature layer within a GeoPackage which has a few value mapped fields as well as the option for attachments. All fields are editable and the layer is set to offline editing (both cloud and cable and I've tried both). I am somewhat new to this so I must be missing something but I cannot find what it might be.

I just made another point layer within the same database and I can edit/add/synchronize it just fine. I'm not sure what might be the cause of this issue, I've followed countless tutorials and looked through the documentation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching it turned out to be something small as I suspected it might. While QGIS desktop as no issue (or at least none that I can see) with brackets within the name of an attribute field I hadn't considered this as the source of error. Turns out that after removing the field with the bracket and re-creating it without it works just fine and I can edit away.

So to summarize, for some reason at this point in time, QField has an issue with brackets in field names, if you have a bracket it won't let you edit but you can add and sync fine. When you remove the bracket, you can do everything as normal.